# Does ZipArchiveEntry Length return wrong size?

Tags: c#, stream, zip

I'm running a service on a device and want to send a file to that service. Easy enough, but the file I want to send comes from a zip file and this is where stuff gets complicated for me.
I'm trying to achieve my goal by sending the stream of the inner file to the device, but then I had to realize that I'm sending 12 bytes (which by the way is the length of the inner filename with extension - coincidence?) more than GetEntry().Length would indicate.

Am I missing something completely or what am I doing wrong?
This is the current code as it is *(Note: client is a valid and connected tcp-socket at this point)*:

```
    System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive zfile = System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.Open(_STR_FILENAME, System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode.Read);
    System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveEntry zentry = zfile.GetEntry(_STR_FWNAME);
    using (Stream fs = zentry.Open())
    {
        using(NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(client))
        {
            int i, counter = 0;

            while((i = fs.ReadByte()) != -1)
            {
                ns.WriteByte((byte)i);
                counter++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("BYTES: " + counter);
            Console.WriteLine("LENGTH FILE: " + zentry.Length);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: I don't see the bug but I'm not motivated to search because you can just use fs.CopyTo(ns).

Comment: sw is unused. Delete it.

Comment: @usr removed the unused streamwriter and also the buffer that wasn't unused. Thanks to point this out. Also thanks for the CopyTo-Approach, but still the question - why hasn't fs the same length as Entry.Length indicates?

Comment: The original code made my eyes hurt. I cleaned it up a little.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the code you posted that would explain why you are getting a different count at the end. So whatever's going on, it's in some code you didn't include, or the code you posted is not the actual code you're using.

Here is some code that simply opens a .zip file and shows the stored length next to the actual bytes that can be read from the stored stream:

```
static void CheckZipEntries(string fileName)
{
    using (Stream inputStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read | FileShare.Delete))
    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(inputStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
    {
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
        {
            using (Stream entryStream = entry.Open())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entry length: {0},   Stream length: {1}",
                    entry.Length, GetStreamLength(entryStream));
            }
        }
    }
}

static int GetStreamLength(Stream stream)
{
    int count = 0, bytesRead;
    byte[] rgb = new byte[1024];

    while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(rgb, 0, rgb.Length)) > 0)
    {
        count += bytesRead;
    }

    return count;
}
```

When I run this on any number of .zip files, both numbers for every single archive entry are identical to each other.

So, I guess the answer to your question is, no it's not actually doing that.